# A keybinding in vim has stopped and I'm stumped

Tags: vim, key-bindings, macvim

I set up a key binding in my .vimrc to allow me to use silver-searcher for quick string searches across my apps.

Currently my  .vimrc looks like this:

```
" .vimrc
set shell=/bin/sh
" load up pathogen and all bundles
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

syntax on                         " show syntax highlighting
filetype plugin indent on
set autoindent                    " set auto indent
set ts=2                          " set indent to 2 spaces
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab                     " use spaces, not tab characters
set nocompatible                  " don't need to be compatible with old vim
set relativenumber                " show relative line numbers
set showmatch                     " show bracket matches
set ignorecase                    " ignore case in search
set hlsearch                      " highlight all search matches
set cursorline                    " highlight current line
set smartcase                     " pay attention to case when caps are used
set incsearch                     " show search results as I type
set mouse=a                       " enable mouse support
set ttimeoutlen=100               " decrease timeout for faster insert with 'O'
set vb                            " enable visual bell (disable audio bell)
set ruler                         " show row and column in footer
set scrolloff=2                   " minimum lines above/below cursor
set laststatus=2                  " always show status bar
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:· " show extra space characters
set nofoldenable                  " disable code folding
set clipboard=unnamed             " use the system clipboard
set wildmenu                      " enable bash style tab completion
set wildmode=list:longest,full
runtime macros/matchit.vim        " use % to jump between start/end of methods
" put git status, column/row number, total lines, and percentage in status
set statusline=%F%m%r%h%w\ %{fugitive#statusline()}\ [%l,%c]\ [%L,%p%%]

" set dark background and color scheme
set background=dark
colorscheme vimbrant

" set up some custom colors
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=7
highlight ColorColumn guibg=Gray
" highlight the status bar when in insert mode
if version >= 700
  au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine ctermfg=235 ctermbg=2
  au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine ctermbg=240 ctermfg=12
endif

" highlight trailing spaces in annoying red
highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=1 guibg=red
match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd InsertEnter * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+\%#\@<!$/
autocmd InsertLeave * match ExtraWhitespace /\s\+$/
autocmd BufWinLeave * call clearmatches()

" set leader key to comma
let mapleader = ","

"silver searcher config
let g:ackprg = 'ag --nogroup --nocolor --column'

" ctrlp config
set runtimepath^=~/.vim/bundle/ctrlp.vim
let g:ctrlp_map = '<leader>f'
let g:ctrlp_max_height = 30
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 0
let g:ctrlp_match_window_reversed = 0

" use silver searcher for ctrlp
let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag %s -l --nocolor -g ""'

" unmap F1 help
nmap <F1> :echo<CR>
imap <F1> <C-o>:echo<CR>

" map . in visual mode
vnoremap . :norm.<cr>

" die hash rockets, die!
vnoremap <leader>h :s/:\(\w*\) *=>/\1:/g<cr>

" map markdown preview
map <leader>m :!open -a Marked %<cr><cr>

" map git commands
map <leader>b :Gblame<cr>
map <leader>l :!clear && git log -p %<cr>
map <leader>d :!clear && git diff %<cr>

" open gist after it's been created
let g:gist_open_browser_after_post = 1

" map Silver Searcher
map <leader>a :Ag!<space>

" search for word under cursor with Silver Searcher
map <leader>A :Ag! "<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR>"

" clear the command line and search highlighting
noremap <C-l> :nohlsearch<CR>

" toggle spell check with <F5>
map <F5> :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<cr>
imap <F5> <ESC>:setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<cr>

" add :Plain command for converting text to plaintext
command! Plain execute "%s/’/'/ge | %s/[“”]/\"/ge | %s/—/-/ge"

" hint to keep lines short
if exists('+colorcolumn')
  set colorcolumn=80
endif

" execute current file
map <leader>e :call ExecuteFile(expand("%"))<cr>

" execute file if we know how
function! ExecuteFile(filename)
  :w
  :silent !clear
  if match(a:filename, '\.rb$') != -1
    exec ":!ruby " . a:filename
  elseif match(a:filename, '\.js$') != -1
    exec ":!node " . a:filename
  elseif match(a:filename, '\.sh$') != -1
    exec ":!bash " . a:filename
  else
    exec ":!echo \"Don't know how to execute: \"" . a:filename
  end
endfunction

" jump to last position in file
autocmd BufReadPost *
  \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
  \   exe "normal g`\"" |
  \ endif

" multi-purpose tab key (auto-complete)
function! InsertTabWrapper()
  let col = col('.') - 1
  if !col || getline('.')[col - 1] !~ '\k'
    return "\<tab>"
  else
    return "\<c-p>"
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <tab> <c-r>=InsertTabWrapper()<cr>
inoremap <s-tab> <c-n>

" rename current file, via Gary Bernhardt
function! RenameFile()
  let old_name = expand('%')
  let new_name = input('New file name: ', expand('%'))
  if new_name != '' && new_name != old_name
    exec ':saveas ' . new_name
    exec ':silent !rm ' . old_name
    redraw!
  endif
endfunction
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>

function! RunTests(filename)
  " Write the file and run tests for the given filename
  :w
  :silent !clear
  if match(a:filename, '\.feature$') != -1
    exec ":!bundle exec cucumber " . a:filename
  elseif match(a:filename, '_test\.rb$') != -1
    if filereadable("bin/testrb")
      exec ":!bin/testrb " . a:filename
    else
      exec ":!ruby -Itest " . a:filename
    end
  else
    if filereadable("Gemfile")
      exec ":!bundle exec rspec --color " . a:filename
    else
      exec ":!rspec --color " . a:filename
    end
  end
endfunction

function! SetTestFile()
  " set the spec file that tests will be run for.
  let t:grb_test_file=@%
endfunction

function! RunTestFile(...)
  if a:0
    let command_suffix = a:1
  else
    let command_suffix = ""
  endif

  " run the tests for the previously-marked file.
  let in_test_file = match(expand("%"), '\(.feature\|_spec.rb\|_test.rb\)$') != -1
  if in_test_file
    call SetTestFile()
  elseif !exists("t:grb_test_file")
    return
  end
  call RunTests(t:grb_test_file . command_suffix)
endfunction

function! RunNearestTest()
  let spec_line_number = line('.')
  call RunTestFile(":" . spec_line_number . " -b")
endfunction

" run test runner
map <leader>t :call RunTestFile()<cr>
map <leader>T :call RunNearestTest()<cr>

" show hidden files in NERDTree
let NERDTreeShowHidden=1

" show hidden files with ctrlp
let g:ctrlp_show_hidden = 1

" Mapping ESC in insert mode and command mode to double i
imap ii <C-[>
cmap ii <C-[>
```

What's weird is when I hit `,A` it works perfectly, but `,a` runs my test suite which is currently mapped to `,t`.

I've been looking at this for hours and I think I'm just missing something dumb. I'm currently using macvim 7.4.52.

Comment: Maybe some plugin is messing with your mappings. What's the output of `:map <leader>a`?

Comment: Thanks @MagnunLeno I get back `,a     ?` when I type that in vim.

Comment: When I run :nmap I see `n  ,a          * :RunAllTests<CR>` -- still baffled on that but I've changed my search to `,s` for the time being.  ::shrug::

Comment: Some plugin must be mapping the `:RunAllTests`. Try moving `map <leader>a :Ag!<space>` to the end of your `.vimrc`